# What graph/dashboard product is facebook using in Dashboard: PUE & WUE

Tags: facebook, charts, dashboard

I love the facebook Dashboard: PUE & WUE. It is beautifull

Can anyone point out if there is an open source or commercial product to offer a similar style?

here is the link
https://www.facebook.com/ForestCityDataCenter?sk=app_288655784601722&app_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just read through 29,888 lines of javascript for ya.. biggest js file I've ever seen. It looks like they make that graph themselves using a variety of tools, including [tween.js](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/). It'd be fascinating to chat with whoever made it. The code for the wheel graph object starts at line 27,266 with the text `var GraphComponent = Class.extend({` . You can find the source at https://www.fbpuewue.com/assets/application-3a3af20f7fa3591229c79442ae3d1c26.js . Sorry if it dissapoints you that it's not an awesome plugin that we can all easily use :/ I share your pain. Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Found `COPIED FROM WHEEL_GRAPH_COMPOSITE.JS` 28,592, but that might just be an internal file..

Comment: yeah, i agree, it is so huge, i tried to go through it and just gave up.

Comment: Thanks mate :), i'll just have to stick with highchart at the moment

Answer (score 2):

We just open-sourced this dashboard code on https://github.com/facebook/puewue-frontend

You'll probably find what you are looking for in https://github.com/facebook/puewue-frontend/tree/master/lib/javascripts

Hope you find it useful!

Comment: Very Nice, Must have taken a while to make. have you got an example, I can follow where it uses mysql